# CRM 2011 Text Field 'Intellisense'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can a text field be given an 'Intellisense' feel?
The user would start typing and be given a list of similar options to choose from.

What about JavaScript that is listening to OnChange 
 of the field and compares the field text to an entities records?

Comment: Actually, I got this weird behavior a few days ago where my computer showed something like that. Not sure if I've saved a screenshot but in my case it wasn't requested, intended nor wanted. I assumed it's some new feature in UR12. After a few hours, it disappeared. Explanation? Beats me...

Comment: If you want it back use JQueryUI...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great tool for accomplish that: jquery autocomplete, see here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

See this posts for using JQuery in CRM 2011:

http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/using-jquery-in-crm-2011/

http://www.crmnerd.com/customizations/using-jquery-in-crm2011/

Comment: jQuery UI Autocomplete is a greate tool. Thank you for exposing me to it. I am not sure that I will be able to add it to the CRM form, but I will try.

Comment: See the other two links is about that add jQuery to crm 2011. Make a simple operation for example put the field enabled or diabled. After that try use autocomplete

Comment: It works well. I had to inject the JQueryUI style sheet into the CRM form.