# crm 2011 lookup autocomplete on a go

Tags: optimization, autocomplete, dynamics-crm-2011, lookup

In dynamics CRM 2011 on a lookup you have an autocomplete feature.

My question is - can you change the (and if yes how) following things in that:

1. Fire it while you typing, not only when it looses focus (like in google....it works while you typing)
2. Make it search for any matches without explicitly writing '*' before and after

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It does fire while typing. The list it shows is based on previously selected items.
2. - To achieve this you can type into the field and press enter to perform a quick search
   - Or you can incorporate jquery autocomplete: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833793/crm-2011-text-field-intellisense][1]